# Change color of tick in ANTD Checkbox

Tags: css, antd

How can I change the color of thing tick inside a checkbox? This is what I have done:

```css
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #008000;
}

.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-input {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Try this, it has all that you want and more styling which you can use. Pretty good for a start.

Comment: @Paulie_D didn't I already produce the code? When you are using ANTD you just need to call `<Checkbox/>` and it will return my checkbox with my CSS

Comment: No you didn't. You gave a snippet of CSS that does not demonstrate the issue, We don't all have ANTD available, your demo should be runnable in the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D this is possibly only a styling issues and you do not need to mention explicitly how to return a checkbox (e.g. `<input type="checkbox"/>`)

Comment: Of course its a styling issue but if you can't demonstrate this NOT working we can't resolve it for you.  An `input` has NO contents so your CSS is not correct as it stands if it's just a bare `input`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this css to your styles:

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner:after {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: it is not working. I will now have a rectangle instead of a tick. I will edit my post to show you how it looks like now.

Comment: i am using V4.4.0 though

Comment: is there any documentations or website that i can read up more on? cause it does not seems to work for me

Comment: sorry, it is still not working. I even created a codesandbox code to test it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-antd-77jxp

Comment: hey I was wondering, since adding a border will make the tick look square, then how could I change the thickness of it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674344/change-thickness-of-checkbox-tick-antd

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone still want to know the answer in 2023. For antd v5, you would add `prefixCls` prop in the `Checkbox` component like this

```
<Checkbox
  prefixCls="show-error"
  ...other props>
  {`ShowError`}
</Checkbox>
```

Then in your CSS file, you would add

```
.show-error-wrapper-checked > .show-error > .show-error-inner {
  background-color: #ff4d4f !important;
  border-color: #ff4d4f !important;
}

.show-error-wrapper > .show-error:hover > .show-error-inner {
  border-color: #ff4d4f !important;
}
```

Importantly, don't forget to add `!important` in your code, and that won't be any caveats of adding it here, since the class name is unique.