# Size of tick does not change when checkbox size increases ANTD

Tags: css, antd

I am using checkboxes from ANT Design and this is the default size of checkbox. [image: default]

Now, I want to increase the size of checkbox, so I changed the width and height and now my checkbox looks like this: [image]

How can I change the size of tick? This is my CSS:

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner{
    background-color: #008000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css to your styles:

```
.ant-checkbox-inner::after {
   width: 13.714286px;
   height: 23.142857px;
}
```

Comment: also, are you able to help me out with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633496/change-color-of-tick-in-antd-checkbox

Comment: It was just a hint to find the correct selector, change it based on your design.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, a simpler way is to use the `scale` css transformation.

Just use this:

```
  .ant-checkbox-inner, .ant-checkbox-input {
    transform: scale(2)
  }
```

The whole box will be scaled twice bigger, including the tick.
Note that you can also use it for values between 0 and 1 to reduce the size of the box.

Comment: Why does this answer have negative points? This is much better than setting width and height and guessing their correct ratio (getting it wrong changes the tick shape).

Comment: I would also like to know!

Comment: Seriously, when somebody gives a negative point, they should at least comment why or make sure the explanation is in the comments already.

Comment: Transform is unreliable in this situation because it will grow the checkbox while not growing its bounding box in the DOM. This means it will become bigger, without shifting the other elements around it, or staying in the position that would be expected. Transform is a purely visual change, rather than a layout change.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    input[type=checkbox]
{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
  transform: scale(2);
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Might want to wrap a span around your checkbox text */
.checkboxtext
{
  /* Checkbox text */
  font-size: 110%;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To accurately scale the checkmark with the checkbox, you will first have to rework how AntD positions it. You can do this by changing the checkbox (`.ant-checkbox-inner`) to a flex layout and then changing the checkmark (`.ant-checkbox-inner::after`) to be relatively positioned.

After doing this, you should be able to get accurate scaling as long as the `scale` transform property aligns with the scale factor you are applying. For example, a 32px checkbox would be 2 times the original size of 16px, so we use `scale(2)`. In mathematical terms, `scaleFactor = checkboxSize / 16`.

```css
.ant-checkbox-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.ant-checkbox-inner::after {
  transform: scale(2) rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: -6%;
  inset-inline-start: 0;
}
```